# Given an API with unordered months, how to index months in order?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a bar chart using an imported React component ([docs](https://nivo.rocks/bar/)) and my months on the X-axis are out of order.

Here's the code and currently the X-axis is ordered by indexBy="month"

```
return(
    <ResponsiveBar
      data={data}
      keys={['purchases']}
      indexBy="month"
      axisBottom={{
        tickSize: 0,
        tickPadding: 10,
        tickRotation: 0,
        legend: 'Month',
        legendPosition: 'middle',
        legendOffset: 50
      }}
     />
)
```

The data={data} refers to an API GET.types.ts file.

```
export type DataResponse = { 
    month: string; 
    year: string; 
    purchases: number; 
}[];
```

How do I index the months in order (from January to December)?